# Javascript remove text input dynamically

Tags: javascript, dynamic

Hi i have the following code..where we can add text input dynamically

what i would like to do is add text input and option to remove text input except the default first one

the add text input is working but not the remove text input

https://jsfiddle.net/ob8n48cg/20/

```
 <script>
var counter = 1;
var limit = 3;
function addInput(divName){
     if (counter == limit)  {
          alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
     }
     else {
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]'>";
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
          counter++;
     }
}


function removeInput(divName){
var newdiv = document.removeElement('div');
              newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]'>";
          document.getElementById(divName).removeChild(newdiv);
 }


</script>


<form method="POST">
     <div id="dynamicInput">
          Entry 1<br><input type="text" name="myInputs[]">
     </div>
     <input type="button" value="Add another text input" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
     <button onclick="removeInput('dynamicInput');">Remove Input</button>
</form>
```

Comment: newdiv is not declared inside of removeInput()

Comment: sorry i edited my code..new on working with javascript..not sure im doing it right or not ..still not working though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
var counter = 1;
        var limit = 3;


function addInput(divName){
     if (counter === limit)  {
          alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
     }
     else {
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]'>";
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
          counter++;
     }
}


function removeInput(event,divName){
        event.preventDefault()
         var parent = document.getElementById(divName)
         parent.removeChild(parent.lastElementChild)
         counter--
         
 }
```

```html
<form>
        <div id="dynamicInput">
             <div>
                    Entry 1<br><input type="text" name="myInputs[]">
             </div> 
             
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Add another text input" onclick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
        <button onclick="removeInput(event,'dynamicInput');">Remove Input</button>
   </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run your code, make sure to check the console window in the browser, checking that shows you have an error in your removeInput function:

```
(index):75 Uncaught ReferenceError: newdiv is not defined
at removeInput ((index):75)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):87)
removeInput @ (index):75
```

onclick @ (index):87

Make sure to define newdiv in the remove function as well as the add function!